# Strange phishing email

Tags: email, phishing

I received a strange phishing email the other day that seemed to use `span` tags to encode "hidden" values within the email's body:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<div dir="ltr">
    <p>P<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>l<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">84</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">35</span>a<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">44</span>s<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">66</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span> C<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">52</span>o<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>n<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>f<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>i<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>r<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">12</span>m<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">75</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">53</span>y<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>o<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>u<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">24</span>r<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">83</span>s<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">66</span>a<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">61</span>c<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>c<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">23</span>o<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">52</span>u<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">55</span>n<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>t<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">74</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">87</span>i<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">61</span>s<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">33</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>f<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">31</span>i<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">11</span>n<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">21</span>a<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">62</span>l<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">61</span>n<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">12</span>o<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">43</span>w<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">23</span>.<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>
        <br>o<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">61</span>p<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">32</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">40</span>n<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">52</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>a<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">82</span>t<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">31</span>t<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">44</span>a<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">49</span>c<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>h<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">82</span>m<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">33</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">92</span>n<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">44</span>t<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>s<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">62</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">51</span>d<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">48</span>o<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">82</span>c<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>x<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">53</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">61</span>h<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">47</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>r<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">62</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">71</span>t<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">45</span>o<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>v<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">64</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">67</span>r<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">94</span>i<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">88</span>f<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>y<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">93</span> <span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">45</span>i<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">74</span>t<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">99</span>.
        <br>
        <br><span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">42</span>S<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">83</span>i<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">24</span>n<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">89</span>c<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">84</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">73</span>r<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">62</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">12</span>l<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">13</span>y
        <br><span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">94</span>A<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">62</span>p<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">62</span>p<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">61</span>l<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">23</span>e<span style="color:transparent;font-size:0px">24</span></p>
</div>
```

When the HTML is rendered it looks like this:

[image: HTML Rendered]

And when you extract only the information between HTML tags it looks like this:

```
P42l84e35a44s66e42 C52o42n42f42i42r12m75 53y42o42u24r83s42 66a61c42c23o52u55n42t74 87i61s33 42f31i11n21a62l42 61n12o43w23.42
o61p32e40n52 42a82t31t44a49c42h82m33e92n44t42s62 51d48o82c42x53 61h47e42r42e62 71t45o42 42v64e67r94i88f42y93 45i74t99.

42S83i24n89c84e73r62e12l13y
94A62p62p61l23e24
```

Of course the email also contained a word doc attachment that is probably the real payload, but I'm wondering what the point of this weird encoding is, besides just looking cool?

There is a similar post on stackexchange [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152052/unusual-phishing-email), but I'm more wondering if anyone has any theories about the encoded sequence of numbers and if it has any meaning.

The number sequence itself is:

```
4284354466425242424242127553424224834266614223525542748761334231112162426112432342613240524282314449428233924442625148824253614742426271454242646794884293457499428324898473621213946262612324
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of this is to fool automated phishing and spam detection algorithms. The trick is simply to supply text which, when rendered by your browser, is easily recognizable by a human but, when parsed by naïve spam filters, does not contain any recognizable signs of malice. The number sequence doesn't mean anything. It's displayed at 0px with a transparent font, which makes it invisible when rendered. It's just filler to avoid detection and was probably selected by randomly mashing number keys.

Comment: Yes, so yes. I've not ever seen legit email use spans, so anything with a span tag I mark as spam and treat accordingly.